# Can you use an OutputStreamWriter in SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview, fileoutputstream

I would like to write a highscore out to a file from a SurfaceView. Is this possible?
I have this piece of code:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        openFileOutput("highscore.txt",0));
```

But it tells me that the method openFileOutput(string, int) is undefined for the type "BoardView" (boardview is my surfaceview)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openFileOutput` is a method of **context**, so you should pass your surface view a context (your activity for example) and use it as `yourActivityObject.openFileOutput("highscore.txt",0)` to use this method.

Comment: I have a context already in my boardview...how will I utilize it?

Comment: if your context object is called `myContext`, then use `myContext.openFileOutput("highscore.txt",0)`

Comment: so it's one of two - either your context is null, which means you didn't pass context to the view, or the file path is wrong. separate the method to two methods: `FileOutputStream fos = myContext.openFileOutput("highscore.txt",0); OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);` and see if `fos` is `null` after the first line, if so - you have a wrong path.

Comment: Does the file "highscore.txt" have to be created before I try to use it? I am sure back in the day when I used to use these kinds of things if it didn't exist then it would be created.

Comment: No. it will be created if it doesn't exist, but maybe this is an invalid path. have you checked what I suggested?

Comment: I used the OutputStreamWriter, but I'm still getting a nullpointer. Perhaps I need to write out a full path?

Comment: where do you get it, on which object?